# TOAD Oracle out of memory when importing queries : 7C86

Tags: database, oracle, toad

I have a .sql file that contains lots of insert statements (the file is 125mb). I want to open it in toad and execute the statement. If i try to copy and paste or file>open>file.sql it fails due to out of memory exception.

How do i increase memory? how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

Toad is not the best way to import large sql-file. You can do that in `sqlplus`. Login in your schema and then load your sql-flie using @ (for example is `@C:\sql.sql`) -

```
c:\>sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on ╧э ╬ъЄ 5 19:58:20 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: MY_SCHEMA@MY_SERVER
Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> @C:\sql.sql

1 row created.

1 row created.

....

SQL> commit
  2  /

Commit complete.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You entered the field of ETL, where SQL is not so handy. For each row there is too much overhead. Also using a developer tool as TOAD is not the thing. Yes, Toad is the abbreviation for "Tool for Oracle Application Developers". The best you can do is creating an so called external table.

[RTFM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/bi-datawarehousing/twp-data-loading-oracle-db-12c-2189777.pdf)